# SQL Server 2012 classic asp connection string

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic, connection-string

I have a SQL Server 2012 Express installation with a new DB called `BRD` that I have created.  I have also created a test table (`tempDemo`), and a test stored procedure (`getStList`) in the `BRD` database. The stored procedure works when I run it in the query window so I believe the table and stored procedure are legit. The SQL Server is set to "SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode".

I then attempted to create a Classic ASP page that then connected to the SQL Server using the following connection string:

```
objConn.ConnectionString="Provider=SQLOLEDB;Server=XPSI7\SQLEXPRESS;Database=BRD;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
```

This fails with the following message:

> "Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server error '80004005'
>   Cannot open database "BRD" requested by the login. The login failed."

When I change the database to `MASTER` instead of `BRD` the ASP page does not error out. I'm just testing the connection string by opening it and then closing it, but it appears to work.

I've looked at the security settings for `MASTER` and `BRD` in the Object Explorer, but have failed to notice a difference. I've also looked at the `IIS_IUSRS` for the folders, but no difference either - not sure if this is necessary anyway.

Comment: The user you're attempting to use -- is it listed under the Security tab for the BRD database?  Clearly it's a valid login, but doesn't appear to be associated with the BRD database...  As long as the listing is linked to a valid login, it's a database permission issue.

Comment: Thank you for the amazingly quick reply OMG Ponies. The question is a good one, however, I'm a little confused on it. What exactly is the "user"? In the connection string I'm not specifying one (I don't think). To attempt to answer your question I have a Guest under each User, however the BRD guest has a red down arrow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL Server authenticates your login at the server level. Then it tries to open the database you've asked to connect to. At this point, you need to either map a database-level user to the server-level login, or use a server-level login that inherently has sufficient privileges to use the database.

A simple (but not secure) way to demonstrate this using SQL Server Authentication:

```
USE master;
GO
CREATE LOGIN foo
  WITH PASSWORD = 'bar', CHECK_POLICY = OFF;
GO
USE BRD;
GO
CREATE USER foo FROM LOGIN foo;
GO
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_owner', N'foo';
GO
```

Now in your ASP connection string, use:

> objConn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLNCLI;Data Source=XPSI7\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=BRD;User ID=foo;Password=bar;"

You can also map whatever login you're using to a database user simply doing:

```
USE BRD;
GO
CREATE USER [YourDomain\IIS_IUSRwhatever] 
  FROM LOGIN [YourDomain\IIS_IUSRwhatever];
GO
```

That will grant them access to the database, but it will be up to you to decide what permissions to grant. This assumes that you are allowing anonymous access to the web server; if IIS is challenging and accepting Windows authentication, you'll need to do the above for the user(s) that will be submitting their credentials. In either case you should be able to continue using the connection string you have now.

Comment: Thank you Aaron. Your answer was concise, simple to understand and correct. You mention that this is not very secure. If I wanted to avoid the embedded USER ID & PASSWORD approach and use Integrated Security=SSPI in the connectionString how much more work is involved?

Comment: The insecure part was about giving the app user db_owner ... Usually you wouldn't give that much to a SQL auth or Windows auth user. I don't really see a reason to use windows auth here if you are just using the IIS account. With a SQL auth account the nice thing is that you can easily connect and debug as the same user. You would use windows auth I think if you were actually authenticating through the web site and passing along the Windows credentials. The plus side here is it's easier to track down who is doing what. But you need to set up individual logins/users or use windows groups...

Comment: @AaronBertrand you could expand your answer noticing the diferences between providers SQLNCLI correspond to "SQL Server 2005 Native Client" , SQLNCLI10 to 2008 driver and SQLNCLI11 to SQL Server 2012

Comment: If this answer does not help you may be you need a reboot. I coul dnot connect and I usually set up a SQL Server account for applications to use as this answer suggests. I restored an old database to this newly installed SQL 2012 installation and while .NET was working Classic ASP just would not. I had timeouts. After shutting down on Friday and starting up today it just works. I guess a reboot helped somehow but I cannot explain it. I did not do anything extra to make it work and the web app works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following connection string:

```
strConnection = "Provider=SQLNCLI10;Server=server_name;Database=" & BD_REMOTE_INITIAL_CATALOG & ";Uid=" & BD_REMOTE_USER_ID & "; Pwd=*****;"
```