# How to connect to local database using ASP classic :(

Tags: sql, asp-classic

I have connected to my local database through SQLSMS using the string (LocalDb)\v11.0

It opened up a connection and I could add a database.

In my ASP classic code (don't ask :( C#.NET FTW!.. damn clients) I have the following code:

```
objConn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Persist Security Info=True;Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=databasename"
```

It is returning this error: Invalid authorization specification

I have no idea what to put in for the User Id and Password parameters?

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to use SQL server authentication for this:

```
objConn.ConnectionString = "User ID=<sql server user id>;Password=<password for sql server user>;Initial Catalog=<database>;Data Source=<database server\instance name>;Provider=SQLOLEDB"
```

Actually looks like there is a previous question ['SQL Server 2012 classic asp connection string'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10972481/sql-server-2012-classic-asp-connection-string) that might cover this in more detail.

Answer (score -1):

Here's an example connection string (SQL Server 2014 on `localhost`):

```
cnstring = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=dATABASEnAME;UID=sqlsERVERUser;PWD=yourPassword;"
```